# Protege OWL Subclass of two classes

Tags: rdf, owl, protege

Is there any problem with having a class in OWL which is a subclass of two different classes?

Comment: Why should it be a "problem"? Note, having two superclasses is the same as a single subClassOf relation to the intersection. That is exactly the definition of the formal semantics of OWL. For example, `A SubClassOf B` and `A SubClassOf C` is equivalent to the axiom `A SubClassOf (B and C)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is exactly the definition of the formal semantics of OWL. For example, A SubClassOf B and A SubClassOf C is equivalent to the axiom A SubClassOf (B and C)

Comment: Any source for that?