# How is: "A subclassOf of B, C" interpreted? As AND or OR in rdfs / owl / description logic?

Tags: owl, semantic-web, rdfs, reasoning, description-logic

Is the following interpreted as the intersection (AND) in the sense that members of class A are members of B and C; or as the disjunction (OR) that members of A are a member of B, or a member of C, or member of both?

```
A rdf:type owl:Class ;
   rdfs:subClassOf some B; 
   rdfs:subClassOf only C.
```

Thanks for clarification how this is interpreted!

I found it as AND: [Protege OWL Subclass of two classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47889590/protege-owl-subclass-of-two-classes)

But Hermit breaks it and uses single axioms (e.g. A rdfs:subclassOf B) as explanation for A to B. I thought that would not be possible ...? Since I would say that A is a subclassOf (B and C) and not only A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can quote [RDFS](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_classes), and considering OWL should follow from that, I don't expect any difference there:

> If a class C is a *subclass* of a class C', then all instances of C will also be instances of C'. The `rdfs:subClassOf` property may be used to state that one class is a subclass of another.

Class inheritance axioms in RDFS are built so that a contradiction can never occur, thus a statement like this can only be "additive" in a sense. Additionally, from the nature of triples in RDF, we know that `A rdfs:subClassOf B, C.` means `A rdfs:subClassOf B. A rdfs:subClassOf C.`.

Expressed in the language of sets, such a construction means A ⊆ B ∧ A ⊆ C. Any member of A is also a member of B, *and* any member of A is also a member of C, thus any member of A must be a member of both B and C. We can see that A ⊆ (B ∩ C), from the duality of set and logical operators.

Expressed equivalently, any member of B not found in C must also not be in A (and the same for B and C swapped).

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Is there any reason why you use first ∧ and later ∩ for a logical and?  A ⊆ B ∧ A ⊆ C vs. A ⊆ (B ∩ C). First is the logical and and second the intersection symbol.

Comment: So as a summary: If there is not any OR (i.e. union-operator) written / shown in a turtle serialization, it is interpreted as an intersection.

Comment: @user3352632 For the symbols, this is what is used in logic when working with sets. In the first case it is a logical conjunction of statements, i.e. both must be true. This can be satisfied if and only if A is a subset of their intersection.

Comment: @user3352632 RDF statements are normally treated in conjunction, i.e. all triples in a graph hold at the same time, not just a single one of them. So the universe of truth is gradually narrowed by every triple, until what results is the intersection of all of that.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense! Now I think I got it! Thanks for your help!